# Как отслеживать запуски программы на python?

Tags: python, файлы, tkinter

задача состоит в следующем: **программу можно запускать не более шести раз,количество запусков каждый день фиксируется в отдельном  текстовом файле**. Пытался искать в интернете как сделать так, чтобы хотя бы отслеживались запуски программы, но ничего дельного не нашёл.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import datetime

root = Tk()
root.title('main')
root.geometry('300x300')


def develop_label(mark_index):
    marks = ['1', '2', '3']
    lbl1['text'] = marks[mark_index]  # меняем свойство text виджета на значение из списка marks
    if mark_index == len(marks) - 1:  # если сейчас последний элемент
        mark_index = -1
    root.after(5000, develop_label, mark_index + 1)  # (интервал в мс, функция, аргумент функции)


lbl1 = Label(text='1', font='TimesNewRoman 12')
lbl1.place(x=120, y=10)

#считать дату(день) и записать в файл дату, затем, когда N=6 сравнить дату с компа с датой в файле и если совпадает то делит, если не совпадает, то перезаписываем новую дату в файл и N = 1

file = open('count.txt', 'r+')
N=file.read(1)

file2 = open('date.txt', 'r+')


if N == 0:
    file2.seek(0)
    file2.write(str(date_now))
    file2.close()
    file2 = open('date.txt', 'r+')
    data_in_file = file2.read()
    file2.close()
    print('aboba')



data_in_file = ''

date_now = datetime.date.today()
date_now1 = str(date_now)
file.close()


file = open('count.txt', 'r+')
file.seek(0)
N = int(N)
N += 1
file.write(str(N))

print(date_now)
print('Дата со 2-го файла', data_in_file)

if int(N) == 6:
    print('rabotaet')
    if date_now1 == data_in_file:
        print('data rabotat')
        exit()
    else:
        file2 = open('date.txt', 'r+')
        file2.seek(0)
        file2.write(str(date_now))
        N = 0


    


k = 0
def correct():
    global k
    path = "C:\\Users\\Gamer\\Desktop\\fuf"
    file_name = 'test.py'
    file_path = os.path.join(path,file_name)    
    a = field.get()
    if a == "йцу":
        print('asdasd')
        lbl2 = Label(root, text = 'Correct',borderwidth = 5)
        lbl2.place(x=120, y=50)
        
    else:
        lbl2 = Label(root, text = 'Incorrect')
        lbl2.place(x=120, y=50)
        k += 1
        print(k)
        if k == 3:
            print(k,"yeees")
            #os.remove(file_path)
            root.destroy()
        
        
field = Entry()
field.place(x=100, y=100)
file.close()
file2.close()
butt = Button(root, text ="go", command = lambda:correct())
butt.place(x=100, y=200)
root.after(0, develop_label, 0)  # (интервал в мс, функция, аргумент функции)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Пусть программа при запуске пишет в файл данные

Comment: Сейчас попробую реализовать, изначально в тхт файле значение=0, каждый запуск мы считываем и перезаписываем это значение на +1 и если оно выходит >6 то exit()

Comment: могу добавить свой код, если вам будет удобнее

Comment: @asd123 сразу нужно было

Comment: я новенький просто  не понял как правильно вставлять

Comment: @asd123 сверху можете найти пункт "код" там же будет тройной штрих которым вы отделяете код.

```
тут код
```

Comment: спасибо, разобрался и добавил

Comment: Как только найду время вам помочь сразу это сделаю.

Comment: @DaYa Здравствуйте, я пытался через строки в новом файле,те записывается дата  в новый файл и проверяется с текущей, но не безуспешно.....

Comment: Вы пробовали записывать дату первого запуска и делать проверку при запуске мол если дата запуска не равна сохранённой дате в файл - обнуление count в противном случае сохранение count.

Comment: @DaYa Не совсем правильно понял, просто надо чтобы программу можно было запускать не более 6 раз и следующий запуск можно было совершить на следующий день, для этого я создал отдельный текстовый файл с датой, сделал проверку, что дата текущая сравнивается с датой из файла, если они не совпадают, то N = 0 и надо чтобы файл c датой каждый раз не перезаписывался файл при запуске и это не получилось реализовать.

Comment: Вы всё правильно сделали, а решением вашей проблемы будет сначала сравнивать текущую дату с записанной а потом уже при надобности перезаписывать дату. Это можно реализовать через обычные операторы if else

Comment: @DaYa Проблема в том, что у меня сделано через операторы, но не срабатывает. Могу добавить код , если в комментариях как-то можно добавить код.

Comment: @asd123 если хотите дополнить кодом. Измените ваш вопрос и внесите туда код. Не рекомендуется сувать код в комментарии.

Comment: @DaYa сейчас исправлю код в вопросе

Comment: @asd123 для начала думаю вам стоит делать проверку сразу после импортов когда основной код только запланирован для запуска.  Остальная часть кода мне в принципе не сильно понятна, зачем использовать `root.destroy()` если можно использовать просто `exit()`, или вам так лучше?

Comment: @DaYa Сделал проверки if N == 0:  и if int(N) == 6: после импортов, но результат тот же.

Comment: @asd123 попробуйте поменять `if` и `else` местами. Т.е если дата сейчас `!=`  записанной дате обнуляем в противном случае оставляем.  Так же рекомендую вам поставить вместо `== 6` , `>=6`